# App takes binary Input from user and blinks flashlight transmitting the input when a button is pressed in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, binary-data, flashlight

SO i am trying to create an app that transmits the user input through blinking flash light. When i use a fixed String myString = "1010101" the flashlight blinks so my app is able to access the flashlight. However, when i take an input from the user and save it in String myString, i press the button but nothing happens. For now i only want to  take binary input. Please Help me out.

```
EditText binData;
Button blinkMode;
boolean isFlashOn = false;
Camera camera;
String myString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    camera = camera.open();

    binData = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    blinkMode = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    myString = binData.getText().toString();

    blinkMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            long blinkDelay = 50; //Delay in ms
            for(int i=0; i<myString.length(); i++){
                if(myString.charAt(i)=='1'){
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    isFlashOn = true;


                } else if(myString.charAt(i)=='0') {

                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    isFlashOn = false;

                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            int length=myString.length();
            if(length == myString.length() ) {
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.stopPreview();
                isFlashOn = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thread.sleep on the UI thread ? Devil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line

```
myString = binData.getText().toString();
```

inside the `onClick()` method. That should ideally fix your issue. You are accessing the string before the button click is made. My guess is that empty string was being taken so far.

Comment: Thanks. It helped! :)